# Disable multisite-wide plugins on specific sites

Tags: plugins, multisite

On a multisite network, I have some plugins that are network activated so they run on every site in the network. However, I want to disable all of the network active plugins on some of the sites.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multisite-wide active plugins are stored in the `active_sitewide_plugins` site option. We can hook into this option and return an empty array (no plugins are active).

This snippet should be installed as a [Must-Use Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

```
<?php
 
/**
 * Plugin Name: Disable Sitewide Plugins
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/107732/19726
 * Author: Shea Bunge
 * Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/19726/shea
 * Version: 0.1
 */

global $blog_id;
 
if ( in_array( $blog_id, array( 6, 9, 42 ) ) {
    add_filter( 'pre_site_option_active_sitewide_plugins', '__return_empty_array' );
}
```

Remember to replace `array( 6, 9, 42 )` with an array of the blog IDs you want to disable network-wide plugins on.